# Querying for Bit/boolean values in vba

Tags: sql, vba

I have a field column that contains a boolean, this boolean is shown as either -1, 0, or, apperently, 0 meaning null.
When I use this value in a where clause, testing if it's false, I get all of the false records, as I should. I am testing this with a 3-state checkbox. If I put this on NULL, then I get no records (null is not allowed in the fields). However, when I turn it to true, I get shown nothing as a result.

Any ideas?

edit:

The query I'm using is not very interesting, it's basically just:
    `"SELECT *a lot* FROM *a lot* WHERE T0001_orders.t0001_active = " & me.chkbx.value`
I believe I'm using SQLserver (?) and I connect via ODBC. That might be incorrect, I haven't bothered too much with that part, which is probably why I can't figure this out.

Comment: a few bits are missing her: post your queries and results. a sample of what the database look like would be useful too. What database are you using and how are you connecting to it?

Comment: well, when I got to work here this part was already set up, so I'm not super sure, but I'll try to add some more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably having issues of null. WHen you use where something = NULL it will not work in msssql server.

You will have to use where something is null

try these 3 statements and you'll probably see where the error lies.

```
SELECT a lot FROM a lot WHERE T0001_orders.t0001_active is null
SELECT a lot FROM a lot WHERE T0001_orders.t0001_active =0
SELECT a lot FROM a lot WHERE T0001_orders.t0001_active =1
```

Is  null returns all the NULL values

field = 1 returns all true

field = 0 returns all false

Comment: for this particular field, is null returns nothing, =0 returns all the false fields, and -1 returns nothing aswell

Comment: alright, <> 0 seems to work, so I'll use that, my question on how to properly query for true still stands though

Comment: strange though. Try 
select count(*),T0001_orders.t0001_active from alot group by T0001_orders.t0001_active 
To see if there are any other values. 

Vba.false = 0 AND ANY OTHER number is true, though the real true = -1

Comment: Ah, that's clever! Unfortunatly there really is only true and false (there are no nulls in this column allowed)

Comment: ... woa, alright, I must have messed up something somewhere because this sure as hell didn't work when I tried it before! But thanks a ton! that works XD